# Show and Hide table through a button click React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Basically i have 3 tables and these tables have 3 titles on the top. Each time i click this title i want to hide the table and show it back. How can i make that happen?

I added a on click to each of the titles, but i can't hide only the table which belongs to this button, it's hiding all the tables? Keep in ming they are all rendered through.

Is there any way to find like if the indexes of the button with the indexes of the table match, then `display: none;` or something?
I tried doing it with dom.querySelectorAll, and mapped through the array but it's hiding everything.

Answer (score 0):

set an array using useState

```
tables = [true,true,true]
```

Only display tables for which the index is true. example in the return ()

```
{tables[0] ? <Table1/> : null}
{tables[1] ? <Table2/> : null}{tables[2] ? <Table3/> : null}
```

Then, use onClick to set the state of the tables array. To dynamically render the tables.
ex. onClick={()=> set table index to false}

Comment: I have them rendered on a map function not like that , i can't do it like that

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
  
  const [table1, settable1] = useState(true);
  const [table2, settable2] = useState(true);
  const [table3, settable3] = useState(true);

async function table1(){
settable1(!table1)
           }

async function table2(){
settable2(!table2)
           }
async function table3(){
settable3(!table3)
           }


return (
{table1== true ? <Table1/> : null}
{table2== true ? <Table1/> : null}
{table3== true ? <Table1/> : null}
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).